# Fetching before render with multiple fetch request

Tags: reactjs, fetch

```
import React from "react";

class Admin extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isFetching: true


  }

  componentDidMount = () => {

    this.getProfile()
    this.getPost()
    this.setState({isFetching: false})




  }

 getProfile = () => {
     fetch(url)
     .then (fetch stuff)

 }


 getPost = () => {
     fetch(url)
     .then (fetch stuff)

 }


  render() {

    if (this.state.isFetching) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    } else {
      return (

        <div>



        </div>

      );
    }
  }
}

export default Admin;
```

The goal is basically I want to fetch all my data then render. I set an isFetching state as true so it returns only loading ti'll then because it errors if it renders unfetched.

This current code does not work. It still renders with its not fully data isn't fully fetched. How do I ensure isFetching becomes false only after every data is fetched. (I have 2 fetch functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use async/await for the fetch

```
 getProfile = async () => {
     const profile = await fetch(url)
     return profile //or whatever you need to do with it

 }

 getPost = async () => {
     const post = await fetch(url)
     return profile //or whatever you need to do with it

 }
```

Comment: That didn't work either. I think its because in .then (fetchStuff) I'm setting states inside this block i.e. this.setState({users: response.json}).